# Order By two columns in the row

Tags: mysql

I have two prices from two tables, which are joined. I need order rows by price from both tables. When first price is zero or null, then take second price, else take first price. So order by part has to be changed.

**SQL**

```
SELECT table1.id
     , table1.price
     , table2.price FROM table1
  JOIN table2  
    ON table1.id = table2.f_id 
 ORDER 
    BY table1.price ASC
     , table2.price ASC
```

**Table1**

```
id / price
1 / 50
2 / 0
3 / NULL
4 / 10
```

**Table2**

```
f_id / price
1 / 60
2 / 30
3 / 5
4 / 100
```

**I expect**

```
3 / 5
4 / 10
2 / 30
1 / 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use case

```
SELECT table1.id
    CASE WHEN table1.price is null THEN table2.price
         WHEN table1.price = 0 THEN table2.price
         ELSE tabel1.price
    END as my_price
JOIN table2   ON table1.id = table2.f_id 
ORDER BY my_price ASC
```

Comment: Only option tbh. My answer lacks the case when the price is `0`. Musst have overlooked that one.

Comment: Mine is a suggestion using CASE in this way all conditions are explicitly visible and therefore can faciltarne understanding for users who are not very experienced in sql

Answer (score 2):

`ifnull` is designed for that purpose (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/):

```
SELECT 
   `table1`.id, 
   ifnull(`table1`.price, `table2`.`price`) as finalPrice 
FROM `table1`
  INNER JOIN `table2` ON table1.id = table2.f_id ORDER BY finalPrice ASC
```

Comment: Note that COALESCE() conforms to the ANSI standard

Comment: @Strawberry what coalesce do with that?

Comment: @tomasr It's a very similar function, but it's database agnostic.

Comment: @Strawberry and could you show example for this query, please?

Comment: replace `ifnull` with `coalesce`, that's all.

Comment: It is not do that job. If in table1 is price 5 and table2 is price 10 the finalPrice is 10. So it is opposite than I wanted.

Comment: Your question was about a price that is `null` or `0` (which i missed as well), so how does your 5 vs 10 example fit in?

Comment: Sorry I badly explain it. First table (table1) is more important. So if in table1 is not null or zero value price is taken from it. So your question is probably best, but for me is working @scaisEdge question

Comment: @tomasr you should accept Scais Answer. Mine is lacking the case, when the price is "zero" (not NULL).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id
 , table1.price
 , table2.price FROM table1
JOIN table2  
 ON table1.id = table2.f_id 
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN table1.price is null THEN table2.price
       WHEN table1.price = 0 THEN table2.price
       ELSE tabel1.price
  END ASC
```

Comment: now check, but it will give t1 and t2 price separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.price is null THEN t2.price
        WHEN t1.price = 0 THEN t2.price
        ELSE t1.price
    END as finalPrice
FROM
    table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE
    t1.id = t2.f_id
ORDER BY finalPrice
```

Instead of using `inner join`, directly compare using `t1.id = t2.f_id`. It will be faster.